# Multiplying values in a listed tuple using python

Tags: python, tuples

I need help on a homework problem that uses a tuple with listed values.

1. A function that examines each block, multiplies shares by purchase price and determines the total purchase price of the portfolio.
2. A second function that examines each block, multiplies shares by purchase price and shares by current price to determine the total amount gained or lost.

We can represent each block of stock as a 5-tuple with purchase date, purchase price, shares, ticker symbol and current price.

```
portfolio= [ ( "25-Jan-2001", 43.50, 25, 'CAT', 92.45 ),
( "25-Jan-2001", 42.80, 50, 'DD', 51.19 ),
( "25-Jan-2001", 42.10, 75, 'EK', 34.87 ),
( "25-Jan-2001", 37.58, 100, 'GM', 37.58 )
]
```

Comment: Show what you have attempted as a solution, please.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Have you tried something that didn't work the way you expected?  If you're just asking for us to write your code for you, that's not a good way to learn (and no one's going to do it).  If you're totally stuck on how how to get started, I'd suggest listing out the steps you'd take as a human before even thinking about code (e.g., "First I'd look at each stock info one at a time... looking for the value of X and comparing to Y")

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the input. I was having trouble with the for loop and how to set it up to pull the right numbers out of the tuple I needed to multiply. Ill post the code, let me know if there are any suggestions. I'm fairly new to Python and coding in general.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate cost (increase the number to read other vars and then add the total, could do for loop but editing on mobile)

```
x = portfolio[0]
res = 1
for i in x[1:3]:
  res *= i
```

Sorry, I can’t help with #2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I wrote. Sorry the indentation isn't working right, I copied from my document in PyScripter.

portfolio= [ ( "25-Jan-2001", 43.50, 25, 'CAT', 92.45 ),( "25-Jan-2001", 42.80, 50, 'DD', 51.19 ),( "25-Jan-2001", 42.10, 75, 'EK', 34.87 ),( "25-Jan-2001", 37.58, 100, 'GM', 37.58 )]

TotalPurchasePrice=0

StartPoint=portfolio[0]

for StartPoint in portfolio:
   SharesxPurchasePrice= StartPoint[2]*StartPoint[1]

TotalPurchasePrice=TotalPurchasePrice+SharesxPurchasePrice

print("Total Purchase Price of the portfolio:", TotalPurchasePrice)

TotalPurchasePrice=0

TotalCurrentPrice=0

StartPoint=portfolio[0]

for StartPoint in portfolio:

SharesxPurchasePrice= StartPoint[2]*StartPoint[1]

TotalPurchasePrice=TotalPurchasePrice+SharesxPurchasePrice

for StartPoint in portfolio:

SharesxCurrentPrice=StartPoint[2]*StartPoint[4]

TotalCurrentPrice=TotalCurrentPrice+SharesxCurrentPrice

print("Total Current Price of the portfolio:", TotalCurrentPrice)

Total=TotalCurrentPrice-TotalPurchasePrice

print("Total gained/lost:", Total)